# Converting a dictionary where each value is a list and each item in that list is another dictionary into a tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, psycopg2

I have a dictionary where each key is an id number and each value is a list of dictionaries, so it looks something like this:

```
{'id number':[{'key1a': 'value1a', 'key2a': 'value2a', 'key3a': 'value3a'},{'key1b': 'value1b', 'key2b': 'value2b', 'key3b': 'value3b'}], 
'id number'...etc.}
```

The dictionary keys within the list are always the same and there are always 3 items in these dictionaries, however, the length of these lists vary.

What I am trying to do is input this dictionary into PostgreSQL with `psycopg2`.

From what I see from the documentation, it is best to input as tuples, so I am trying to convert this information into a list of tuples. The trick is, I need the `ID key` to remain the same, as the first item in the tuple, for each value dictionary item it is paired with.

So the list of tuples should look like this
`[(10001, 1a, 2a, 3a), (10001, 1b, 2b, 3b), (10002,...),` etc. so that the table would look like the one below, if I'm not mistaken.

| ID | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | a | a | a |
| 10001 | b | b | b |

I've tried iterating like so:

```py
for key in dict: 
    for i in key: 
        print(i)
```

(with the right indention), but this just prints the actual characters in the id.
Any help would be appreciated. I'm probably making it more complicated than I need to.

Comment: From [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): *... by using %s placeholders in the SQL statement, and passing a sequence of values as the second argument of the function*. So a `list` is as appropriate as a `tuple`. To be complete: *Named arguments are supported too using %(name)s placeholders in the query and specifying the values into a mapping.*. So a `dict` can be used also.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `dict` to get list of lists.

```
d = {'10001':[{'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'a', 'key3': 'a'},{'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'b', 'key3': 'b'}],
     '10002': [{'key1': 'a2', 'key2': 'a2', 'key3': 'a2'},{'key1': 'b2', 'key2': 'b2', 'key3': 'b2'}, {'key1': 'c2', 'key2': 'c2', 'key3': 'c2'}]}

row_list = []
for id in d:
    for item in d[id]:
        item_list = []
        item_list.append(int(id))
        for ky in item:
            item_list.append(item[ky])
        row_list.append(item_list)
row_list
[[10001, 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 [10001, 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 [10002, 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'],
 [10002, 'b2', 'b2', 'b2'],
 [10002, 'c2', 'c2', 'c2']]
```

Insert data into table

```
create table val (id integer, value1 varchar, value2 varchar, value3 varchar);

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executemany('insert into val values(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row_list)
con.commit()

select * from val;
  id   | value1 | value2 | value3 
-------+--------+--------+--------
 10001 | a      | a      | a
 10001 | b      | b      | b
 10002 | a2     | a2     | a2
 10002 | b2     | b2     | b2
 10002 | c2     | c2     | c2
```

The above uses `executemany` which does not scale well. If you are going to be inserting large numbers of values then:

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch
execute_batch(cur, 'insert into val values(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row_list)
con.commit()
```

This uses `execute_batch` from [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-exec) which inserts(in this case) the data in batches instead of iterating over the data as `executemany` does.

Comment: Thank you! There just seems to be an issue at 'item_list.append(item[ky])',  because 'string indices must be integers'. I'll leave you an example of the actual dictionary. Sorry, I thought it would have been easier to follow an abstract example. You can see that the key is a video id and each item is dictionary for a line of subtitles, with the text, start time and duration. 

'iE1LmiDep2s': [{'text': '- [Narrator] Millions find\na low-cost health plan', 'start': 0.36, 'duration': 2.07}, {'text': 'at HealthCare.gov', 'start': 2.43, 'duration': 1.53}]

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, some of my id's had error messages where there should have been dictionary items, works for me after disregarding those

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood the problem statement, Here's an example code for it. I've taken your sample input as a refernce and its coded in python.

```
    d={111:[{'key1a': 'value1a', 'key2a': 'value2a', 'key3a': 'value3a'},{'key1b': 'value1b', 'key2b': 'value2b', 'key3b': 'value3b'}],222:[{'key1a': 'value1a', 'key2a': 'value2a', 'key3a': 'value3a'},{'key1b': 'value1b', 'key2b': 'value2b', 'key3b': 'value3b'}]}
result = [(int(key), *item.values()) for key, value in d.items() for item in value]
print(result)
```

> OUTPUT : [(111, 'value1a', 'value2a', 'value3a'), (111, 'value1b', 'value2b', 'value3b'), (222, 'value1a', 'value2a', 'value3a'), (222, 'value1b', 'value2b', 'value3b')]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm running into an issue  at 'key, *item.values' 'str' object has no attribute 'values'. Let me give you one of the key-values pairs of the dictionary (below). Sorry, I thought an abstract example would be easier to follow but maybe not. You can see the key is a video id and the items are subtitles, a dictionary for each line with text, start time and duration. 

'iE1LmiDep2s': [{'text': '- [Narrator] Millions find\na low-cost health plan', 'start': 0.36, 'duration': 2.07}, {'text': 'at HealthCare.gov', 'start': 2.43, 'duration': 1.53}]